# Exclude test classes while building Android application using gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-instrumentation

I am trying to develop an interface which lets the user to test his Android classes individually.

To run specific test case in Android Instrument test I was using the following command

**gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.testInstrumentationRunner='package_name.TestClassName'**

I am facing issues if there are any compile errors in other test classes. So as per my use case, I would like to know if there is any command / task in gradle where in I can dynamically exclude unnecessary test classes while building.